# How to print an array from a different subprogram? I'm not too sure on how to print myArray.. I keep getting NameError: name 'myArray' is not defined

Tags: python

```py
def numArrayElements():

  num = int(input("please enter a number "))
  return num
numArrayElements()



def inputArray():

  num = numArrayElements()
  myArray = []
  for i in range(0,num):
    numlis = int(input("please enter a number "))
    myArray.append(numlis)
    
  return myArray
inputArray()

def printArray():
 
  print(myArray)

printArray()
```

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the concept of scope. If you search for "python scope" there will be a number of resources to aid you in understanding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Answer (score 0):

its need to use arguments with functions :

```
def numArrayElements():
    num = int(input("please enter a number "))
    return num

def inputArray(num):
    myArray = []
    for i in range(0,num):
        numlis = int(input("please enter a number: "))
        myArray.append(numlis)
    return myArray

def printArray(myArray):
    print(myArray)

num = numArrayElements()
arr = inputArray(num)
printArray(arr)
```

your get outs:

```
please enter a number 3
please enter a number: 1
please enter a number: 3
please enter a number: 2
[1, 3, 2]
```